# Does Rmpi require an active Internet connection?

Tags: macos, r, parallel-processing, mpi

I just installed `Rmpi` using this tutorial: http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/yu/Rmpi/mac_os_x.htm on Mac OS-X Mountain Lion. I need Rmpi only for making use of all cores and not for deployment on a hardware cluster or similar.

Actually, everything works fine but now I experienced that whenever I don't have an active internet connection (like sitting in the train or just turning wireless of) spawning slaves will fail and I am wondering if this is supposed to work like this?

```
> require( Rmpi )
> mpi.spawn.Rslaves( nslaves=2 )

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
At least one pair of MPI processes are unable to reach each other for
MPI communications.  This means that no Open MPI device has indicated
that it can be used to communicate between these processes.  This is
an error; Open MPI requires that all MPI processes be able to reach
each other.  This error can sometimes be the result of forgetting to
specify the "self" BTL.

  Process 1 ([[56132,1],0]) is on host: ABC-MB02
  Process 2 ([[56132,2],0]) is on host: ABC-MB02
  BTLs attempted: self sm

Your MPI job is now going to abort; sorry.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2 slaves are spawned successfully. 0 failed.
[ABC-MB02:53970] 2 more processes have sent help message help-mca-bml-r2.txt / unreachable proc
[ABC-MB02:53970] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
```

Then the load of my CPUs just jumps to 100% and eventually the R session will crash.

Any ideas how I can avoid this behavior? This is my `sessionInfo`

```
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] graphics  grDevices datasets  stats     utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Rmpi_0.6-3     ggplot2_0.9.3  stringr_0.6.2  reshape2_1.2.2 plyr_1.8      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-1   dichromat_2.0-0    digest_0.6.3       grid_2.15.2        gtable_0.1.2       labeling_0.1      
 [7] MASS_7.3-23        munsell_0.4        proto_0.3-10       RColorBrewer_1.0-5 scales_0.2.3       tools_2.15.2
```

Comment: For a single machine it is often much more convenient and memory efficient to use the `mclapply` and friends family of functions from the `parallel` package; these use shared memory and forks, rather than spawning independent processes. It might also help to add an 'mpi' tag to your question, as it does not really sound R-specific.

Comment: @MartinMorgan thanks for your advice. The problem is that I don't really have control on which parallel library I will use, since the functionality is implemented in other packages I am building on (`xcms` and `CAMERA` from Bioconductor). These packages simply test if either `Rmpi` (preferred) or `snow` are installed and deploy the calculations to as many cores as I specify. However, with `snow` I can circumvent the here described problem but face others.

Comment: These packages are from the same group; perhaps email to `packageDescription('CAMERA')$Maintainer` and also xcms would lead to a long-term solution?

Comment: @MartinMorgan I could, but don't want to bother the maintainer too much, since I sent them recently a couple of issues and feature request with higher priority :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't need an internet connection, but Open MPI seems to fail when you spawn processes if you only have the "self" and "sm" BTL's available, and on my Mac laptop, the "tcp" BTL isn't available unless there is at least one network "Connected" in the "Network Preferences".  It's interesting to note that I was able to use Rmpi successfully when the workers were started by mpirun, rather than being spawned.  Also, I didn't have any problems spawning processes on a Linux machine when it was completely unplugged.

I was able to get my laptop to spawn processes successfully by connecting it to another computer using  an ethernet cable, even to a little Raspberry Pi.  Even though the cable couldn't actually be used for anything, it tricked the Mac into thinking that "Ethernet" was connected, so the "tcp" BTL was available in Open MPI, so spawning processes worked.

Update:

I finally figured out a solution to this problem that works on my MacBook Pro.  By setting the **btl_tcp_if_include** MCA parameter to "lo0", you can force Open MPI to use the loopback interface for TCP communication when your laptop isn't connected to any external network.  One way to set it is with an environment variable in your R script:

```
Sys.setenv(OMPI_MCA_btl_tcp_if_include='lo0')
library(Rmpi)
mpi.spawn.Rslaves(nslaves=2)
```

It appears to work as long as you set the environment variable before loading `Rmpi`, which is when MPI_INIT is called.

Comment: Thanks for reproducing the problems and detailing on it. But as you mentioned, it does not really solve my problem. So I was hoping that there could be some compilation option for MPI avoiding this behaviour.I'm also wondering if it's possible to connect a "faked" device, i.e. just let the OS think a device is connected, that the TCP BTL becomes available.

Comment: @Beasterfield: I was wondering about a Bluetooth device since "Bluetooth PAN" is one of the listed networks, but it doesn't work with my cell phone.

Comment: Obviously there seems to be no better solution. So thanks for this.

Comment: @Beasterfield: Hopefully my update will provide a better solution.